# ContextMenu shows without right and bottom border every second time

Tags: javafx, contextmenu, hbox

I made contextMenu on element SubjectListItem which extends HBox like this:

```
@FXML
private void onContextMenuRequested(ContextMenuEvent e) {
    contextMenu.show(
            SubjectListItem.super.getParent(),
            e.getScreenX(),
            e.getScreenY()
    );
}
```

Variable contextMenu is private final field of SubjectListItem, and it is set:

```
private class SubjectCell extends ListCell<Subject> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(final Subject subject, final boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(subject, empty);
        if (subject != null) {
            setGraphic(new SubjectListItem(subject, SubjectListView.this.markService, eventBus, faceAnalysisService));
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

on ListView by list.setCellFactory(c -> new SubjectCell());

The problem is that every second time (second, forth...) the borders (right and bottom are cut:
[image: Cut borders of ContextMenu]

But first, third... times it is ok. It is bug of javafx or I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found hack to fix it.
Before line:

```
contextMenu.show(...);
```

I must add line:

```
contextMenu.hide();
```